# wPaint.js - save image

Tags: javascript, html, paint

I used http://wpaint.websanova.com/ on my webpage but how can I save image by clicking a my own button (not this from scrript)

```
<button type="submit" id="test" value="Submit" onclick="test()">TEST!!</button>
```

this is script from wPaint.js menu:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.wPaint.menus.main.items, {
save: {
  icon: 'generic',
  title: 'Save Image',
  img: img,
  index: 0,
  callback: function () {
    this.options.saveImg.apply(this, [this.getImage()]);
  }
},
```

and this is script from wPaint.js:

```
var images = [
      '../test/uploads/wPaint.png',
    ];

    function saveImg(image) {
      var _this = this;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../test/upload.php',
        data: {image: image},
        success: function (resp) {

          // internal function for displaying status messages in the canvas
          _this._displayStatus('Image saved successfully');

          // doesn't have to be json, can be anything
          // returned from server after upload as long
          // as it contains the path to the image url
          // or a base64 encoded png, either will work
          resp = $.parseJSON(resp);

          // update images array / object or whatever
          // is being used to keep track of the images
          // can store path or base64 here (but path is better since it's much smaller)
          images.push(resp.img);

          // do something with the image
          $('#wPaint-img').attr('src', image);
        }
      });
    }
```

my script:

```
function test()

{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the image inside your function with $('#wPaint').wPaint('image')